# How to use "Block Public Access" setting in JAVA (Amazon S3)?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I'm trying to implement the logic for blocking public access to the S3 bucket. First I'm creating a bucket and later assigning the permissions to the bucket. I'm facing an issue that a bucket is getting created on the Amazon S3 instance, but blocking public access permission is not getting assigned.

Following is the code -

```
CreateBucketRequest createBucketRequest = new CreateBucketRequest(bucket);
PublicAccessBlockConfiguration publicAccessBlockConfiguration = new PublicAccessBlockConfiguration();
s3Object.createBucket(createBucketRequest);
publicAccessBlockConfiguration.setRestrictPublicBuckets(true);
```

I'm not getting what I'm doing wrong.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to run / perform a https://docs.amazonaws.cn/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/SetPublicAccessBlockRequest.html

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

This is a few months old but to properly close this with an example:

```
this.s3Client.putPublicAccessBlock(PutPublicAccessBlockRequest.builder()
        .publicAccessBlockConfiguration(
                PublicAccessBlockConfiguration.builder().blockPublicPolicy(true).build())
        .bucket(bucketName).build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to call [putPublicAccessBlock](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html#putPublicAccessBlock-java.util.function.Consumer-) to send the configuration to S3.

Comment: Can you give me an example?